# how to secure connection to google database using public ip (0.0.0.0)?

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-platform

I have created software in which I'm connecting with google database using public IP but as with changing network, the public IP changes for the system. So for ease, I used the IP 0.0.0.0 but it's not secure but I don't know any other option as I'm new to this. So is there any way to secure it.

Comment: Maybe you can get static IP for your Google DB which won't change?
One of another way is, for example, use some kind of discovery server which will return actual IP of your DB on every request. It's not a good solution but it can work while you have no ability to use static IP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to set a secure connection to a Cloud SQL instance.

1. Use SSL certs to connect to the instance and enable the "Allow only SSL connections".
2. Use Private IP. I understand that the application that you created is not hosted in GCP, but elsewhere, so, a good option is to:

   2.1. Enable the private IP feature in your CSQL instance

   2.2. Enable "import [custom routes](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering#importing-exporting-routes)" in the just created peering between your project (let's call this project "project A") and the tenant project where your CSQL is (the name of this project will look like "speckle-umbrella-[pg]-xx" JFYI). Bear in mind that this feature is in beta.

   2.3. Ask our technical support team to enable "export custom routes" on the just created peering, but for this time, on our side (in the already mentioned "speckle-umbrella-[pg]-xx" project). If you don't have a support package, you can open a private issue tracker following this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491274) specifying my name, your project ID and the CSQL instance where you want to enable this feature. Don't worry, the issue tracker that you will open there is only visible for Google employees and you. Bear in mind that opening an issue tracker there could take up to 90 days to get an answer, but I'll be monitoring this post.

   2.4. Then, as I assumed that your app is not running in GCP, you will have to set a [VPN tunnel](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/) or a [Cloud interconnect](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/docs/), to connect your local network to Google Cloud.

After this, you'll be able to connect from your app to your CSQL instance in a secure way.

3. If you want to use Private IP and your app is hosted in GCP, you can connect directly to your CSQL instance if your app and CSQL are both in the same region and using the same VPC (If you are using a serverless option such as Cloud functions or Google App Engine Standard you can use [Serverless VPC access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access)). But if your app is hosted in GCP, but in a different project, you can follow the steps 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3, and then, create a VPC peering between the project where your application is (Let's call this project "project B") and the project where you have associated your CSQL instance ("Project A"). For "project A" you will have to enable "export custom routes" in this new VPC peering, and for "project B" you will have to enable "import custom routes". Doing this, your connection between your app (hosted in "Project B") will go from Project B to Project A, and to Project A to speckle-umbrella-[pg]-xx until reach your Cloud SQL instance.

The reason why you have to deal with custom routes is because some time ago, VPC peerings were not able to propagate routes, but now with this is completely possible.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out but I just have one more silly question if you would respond no to it I will follow above provided steps.

What if I just set a password for root?
this will help me avoid unwanted access to the database

Comment: @Krypton_H4x0r Well, you should always have a strong password for the root user (and for all the users in your DB), but from my point of view, it is not enough, if you want to have a secure connection, follow the steps described above please.

Comment: @Krypton_H4x0r - Unless you have also enabled SSL on your connections, your login and password are sent in the clear. Use SQL Proxy.