# Access Google Cloud SQL - SQL Server from Google Cloud Function

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to contact a SQL Server hosted on Google Cloud SQL using Private IP and VPC serverless access in Google Cloud Function)

This is actually not working (The Google Cloud Function reach its timeout) but in the same condition I succeed contacting on the private IP a PostgresSQL server, all other things being equaled (the infrastructure is deployed by Terraform to ensure exact same conditions, I just change the database_version)

The database, the VPC Serverless access and the Google Cloud Functions are all deployed in the same region.

Is there any workaround or solution to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the oficial documentation [Connecting to Cloud SQL from Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions), you will see that there is no support for connecting to SQL Server Beta from Google Cloud Functions.

> This page is not available for SQL Server database engine

Comment: Yes no official support for google cloud_sql_proxy, but wondering if there is an unofficial option. For example according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60396509/serverless-vpc-access-connectors-unable-to-connect-to-cross-region-network-res), it's been said it's working in the same region but I can't make it work.